# Apply Interactive Window Width and Center to JPEG Image

Tags: android, image-processing, jpeg, dicom

I have converted Dicom image to JPEG file using Imebra Library. I want to apply Interactive windowing on that displayed JPEG on screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Currently I am using following logic on pixel by iterating each JPEG pixel but it does not correcly applying windowing to JPEG File

[Render Script Code ]

```
displayMin = (windowLevel- windowWidth/2);
displayMax = (windowLevel+ windowWidth/2);

/* Channel */

if(current.r < displayMin)
{
  current.r = 0;
}
else if(current.r > displayMax)
{
   current.r = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imebra now supplies the pre-compiled library for Android, which applies the Windowing in real time when you use the DicomView class (an Android View that displays the Dicom Image).

There is no need to convert to jpeg:
Follow the example in the documentation and then modify the windowing value in the voilut object.

Comment: I tried that previously as you said modified values in VOILUT object and it does work correct but Applying Window Center and Width In VOILUT is very slow as It need to return Bitmap object Every time I want to set any of value from them them interactivity. because I want fast playback of frames I first convert all the frames to JPEG and Save them to disk for later play from Bitmap[]. I cannot use FFMEPG here as per example code in documentation as If I use that i cannot apply image filter to video. I did wrote render scripts for performing pixel operations on JPEG.